# Order all results using Laravel

Tags: laravel, sum, sql-order-by

I have two tables: `users` and `orders`

I can get the total of all the orders of each user using foreach loop

```
$user->orders()->sum('total')
```

But, I can't order it in my view.

I have referred this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29252051/4818758

But, getting only one row. Any idea or link, please?

Thanks

Comment: put your controller code please.

Comment: `sum()` will only return a number, what are you trying to order?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, sincerely. Finally, I've just found this answer, pure gold for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209777/order-by-sum-column-relationship-in-laravel